# SQLite Assembly can't be added to project

Tags: visual-studio, system.data.sqlite

In my Visual Studio app I get the following Build Error:

"The type 'SQLiteConnection' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.105.2, ..."

So I went to Project -> Add Reference... and looked under "Assemblies" whether there was one called 'SQLite' that I might add.

There was none so I went to my package manager and installed the SQLite NuGet.

Then I went again to Project -> Add Reference... and looked under "Assemblies" for 'SQLite'. And again there was nothing !!!

[image]

What the hell is going on here? How can I add a reference to this damn SQLLite?

PS: When I check in the Package manager for the installed packages, SQLite is shown as being installed. But still, it doesn't show up under Project -> Add Reference  ... so I can't add it.

Answer (score 0):

The SQLite Nuget package has to be installed on the projects in your solution, not just installed generally.  I don't know for sure what your solution looks like, but ...

If you have, say, two projects in the solution, and let's say they are a web app or a winforms app with a data access layer class library that is doing SQLite work. You will have to install the SQLite package on both the DAL and the running project.  Simply highlight the project in question in the solution explorer, and then use the Nuget package manager to install the package. Then highlight the next project and do the same with it.  If you only install Sqlite to the DAL library, you'll get an error saying that the interop dll can't be found. For some reason the startup project needs to have the Sqlite package installed on it, even if it isn't using it directly.

I hope this helps -- I'm new to Sqlite myself, and this may not fit your exact trouble.